# dataframe pivot based on 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame like shown below

| customer | organization | currency | volume | revenue | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | XYZ Ltd | CNY, INR | 20 | 3,000 | 01-Oct-2022 |
| John | abc Ltd | INR | 7 | 184 | 01-Oct-2022 |
| Mary | aaa Ltd | USD | 3 | 43 | 03-Oct-2022 |
| John | bbb Ltd | THB | 17 | 2,300 | 04-Oct-2022 |
| Dany | ccc Ltd | CNY, INR , KRW | 45 | 15,100 | 04-Oct-2022 |

If I pivot as shown below

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['runs', 'volume','revenue'],
                        index=['customer', 'organization', 'currency'],
                        columns=['Duration'],
                        aggfunc=sum,
                        fill_value=0
                  )
```

`level = 0` becomes volume for all Duration (level 1) revenue for all Duration duration for all Duration.

I would like to pivot by Duration as level 0 and volume, revenue as level 2.

How to achieve it?

Current output:
[image]

I would like to have date as level 0 and volume, revenue and runs under it.

Comment: Can you add the expected output to your post/question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use swaplevel like below in your current pivot code; try this;

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['customer', 'organization', 'currency'],
                        columns=['Duration'],
                        aggfunc=sum,
                        fill_value=0).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Hope this Helps...